# PHP notice coming from the WordPress core?

Tags: errors, core, notices

Do you also experience this particular notice? ( Of course one has to turn on the DEBUG mode at the wp-config.php to be able to see this kind of a notice ).

```
> Notice: add_shortcode_param is deprecated since version 4.4 (will be
> removed in 5.1)! Use vc_add_shortcode_param instead. in
> F:\inetpub\wwwroot\.......\wp-includes\functions.php on line 3783
```

Since this is coming from one of the core files, it has puzzled me as how it made it to production as such or I'm reading this entire thing in a wrong way.

Comment: It is actually saying `add_shortcode_param` is deprecated. Use `vc_add_shortcode_param` instead of `add_shortcode_param`. `vc_add_shortcode_param` is the upgraded version of `add_shortcode_param`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1) Looks like you are using the Visual Composer Plugin which is a legacy version which has a deprecated function. If you are using old version upgrade your Visual Composer plugin to the latest version which is **5.0.1**.

2) Another case might be your are using a theme which might be using Visual Composer as a third-party plugin and has some Visual Composer Addons which is not updated and still uses that `add_shortcode_param`

**Manual Solutions**
Find in theme files for `add_shortcode_param`. If it doesn't show any then look for the same in your third-party plugins used by your theme and if found then replace those function names with `vc_add_shortcode_param`

Comment: My bad. I did not see the vc_ prefix. Surely it is the visual composer. Thx.

Comment: I though you were not aware of the VC and asked about it. I'm glad my answer helped you.

Comment: thank you... the part "\wp-includes\functions.php" got me! Thought the culprit was coming from the WP Core. Can't believe a plugin as big as VC is still shipping with deprecated functions. thanks for the pointer.